# Making a simple leader board in memory

Tags: javascript

Im trying to think of the most efficient way to structure an in memory leader board with the ability to read a specific rank quickly. Im talking about very micro optimisations as either way it will still be fast.

```
class Leaderboard
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.leaderboard = [];
    }

    insert(name, score)
    {
        const player = new Player(name, score, new Date());
        this.leaderboard.push(player);
        this.leaderboard.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score);
    }

    getRank(rank)
    {
        if (isNaN(rank) || rank < 1 || rank > this.leaderboard.length) return null;
        return this.leaderboard[rank - 1];
    }
}

class Player
{
    constructor(name, score, date)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
        this.date = date;
    }
}

const leaderboard = new Leaderboard();

leaderboard.insert('john', 36);
leaderboard.insert('pete', 23);
leaderboard.insert('dave', 56);

console.log(leaderboard.getRank(2));
```

This is what I have come up with, any feedback is great and any small optimisations or completely different and better ways are welcome, thankyou

Comment: Can you show a bit more about how it is used in a real context please?

Comment: Lets say its an api and the client sends the players name and score. (i know score shouldnt be on the client but its just an example)

Comment: We're usually not so happy to review hypothetical stub code without practical context here. I am going to close vote now, let's see how it develops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Tips and hints ...***

*Namings*:

- `leaderboard` as `Leaderboard` class property could have a more straightforward and comprehensive name - `this.players` (as collection of `Player` instances)
- `getRank` function may be perceived as the one that returns *rank*. 
  In real, it returns a `Player` instance for a specified `rank`. Thus, it's better named as `getByRank`

*Design*:

- In terms of good design `Leaderboard` class should not be responsible for generating a new player with `new Player(name, score, new Date())`.
  `insert` method would optimally accept `Player` instance as a single argument.
  In other cases - `Player` instances could be generated via supplement factory like `PlayerFactory` class
- considering that `this.players` is an internal collection of *players*, a good idea is to prevent a mutation of it from the outer/client scope.
  At least, you could stick to internal convention and named it as "protected" property **`this._players = []`** with further adding **`get`** accessor (used in "strict" mode):

  ```
  get players() {
     return [...this._players];
  }
  ```

  that will return a **copy** of *protected* collection to a client.

---

New version:

```js
"use strict";

class Leaderboard
{
    constructor()
    {
        this._players = [];
    }
    
    get players() {
        return [...this._players];
    }

    insert(player)
    {
        this._players.push(player);
        this._players.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score);
    }

    getByRank(rank)
    {
        if (isNaN(rank) || rank < 1 || rank > this._players.length) return null;
        return this._players[rank - 1];
    }
}

class Player
{
    constructor(name, score, date)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
        this.date = date;
    }
}

const leaderboard = new Leaderboard();

leaderboard.insert(new Player('john', 36, new Date()));
leaderboard.insert(new Player('pete', 23, new Date()));
leaderboard.insert(new Player('dave', 56, new Date()));

console.log(leaderboard.getByRank(2));
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for this, Do you think some sort of hash table would be better for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation depends on `this.leaderboard.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score);`. Each and every time you insert, you sort again.

Depending on your access pattern, you could defer the sorting from *adding* to *reading*.

You could operate with a dictionary keeping the scores unorderd which makes inserting fast. And sort the entries only in case if you read them.

*For the sake of the example I used plain numbers*

```
let leaderboard = {
}

const addScore = (board, score) => {
  if(!board[score]) board[score] = []
  board[score].push(score)
  return board;
}

const getcurrentRanks = (board) => {
    const scoreranks = Object.keys(board).sort((a,b)=>b-a)
    return scoreranks.reduce((o,n )=>{
        return o.concat(board[n]);
    }, []);
}
```

But this has the downside of converging to your first implementation the more you read; e.g. for each time you insert a value you want to get all the ranks.

Otherwise I would encourage you to look into [priority queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

Comment: Thankyou very much for this Thomas, Do you think some sort of hash table would be better for this?

Comment: The answer is like above: _it depends_ on your data. In general: no.